# Error when I try to open up OLE DB Source and Project.params. SSIS complains about font

Tags: sql-server, ssis

When I try to open up a `OLE DB Source` or `Project.params` I get the error:

> Attempt by method 'Microsoft.Data.TransformationServices.Controls.DlgGridControl.OnFontChanged(System.EventArgs)' to access method 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.Grid.GridControl.OnFontChanged(System.EventArgs)' failed.

Does anyone know where this error stems from?

Our DBA had to reinstall our SQL Environment which we had saved on our `E:` disc, whereas my SSIS Project were saved on our `C:` disc so it wasn't affected.

Is there an option I need to select?

Comment: Is this happening when you are editing your package in Visual Studio or when trying to configure it for execution in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: @EmilioCeroleni This is happening when I try to edit the package. When I try to open up my `OLE DB Source` to change the Connection, I can't even open it up. The same happends when I create a new OLE DB Source and try to open that in Visual Studio.

Comment: Sounds to me like some mixed signals in your visual studio.   I'd try uninstall/reinstalling it.

Comment: Which Visual Studio version are you using? You can try reinstalling the latest appropriate version of [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt)

Comment: @TabAlleman    Sorry for the late response. Indeed, reinstalling VIsual Studio removed the error. Feel free to post your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I could say I understand the internals of Visual Studio well enough to explain exactly why this happened, but I don't.   However I suspected this was an internal Visual Studio error because it's a vague error about accessing an event handler (`GridControl.OnFontChanged`) that's built into the .net framework, not an error about the code you wrote.

Therefore I suspected that your Visual Studio installation had gotten corrupted and had some missing elements, and re-installing might fix the problem.   Glad to hear it worked.